# How to change the lock timeout in db2?

Tags: java, db2

I am getting Lock-acquisitionexception when I am running my Application on DB2, so i am suspecting the lock time needs to be changed. So how can I change the same? Or is there any other solutions to avoid exception.

Comment: What platform is DB2 running on, and what version of DB2?

Answer (score 2):

From [Top 10 performance tips](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/hayes/0102_hayes.html)

```
db2 "update db cfg for DBNAME using LOCKTIMEOUT 15"
```

Comment: is it possible to change using the sql console? (for example, for dashdb at ibm cloud)